# Spring Boot with spring-data-elastic connecting to Elastic Search 7.4.0 on AWS server

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I run spring-data-elastic v4.0.1.RELEASE (with org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch 7.6.2 ) with ES client running on 7.4.0??? If not, what combination can I use for 7.4.0 client? We are migrating to AWS and I need to use 7.4.0 version of client.
2. I have parent/child relationship (configured as join datatype field). Could pls somebody provide a documentation or explain, how to use either ElasticsearchRestTemplate or ElasticsearchOperations to correctly insert/update both parent and child records?

Thank you.
Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

ad 1): from the Elasticsearch documentation I can't at the moment find anything in the breaking changes sections that would prevent using a 7.4.0 client library, but that does not mean there aren't any. But that does not mean that there aren't any. Recently there was a breaking change in the Java classes (from 7.7 to 7.8) and I got the information:

> our compatability focus is on the HTTP APIs and we don’t offer any guarantees on the code itself. There’s more background here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22707#issuecomment-274163711

So I'd say, write a small test app and with the corresponding libraries, start a local ES 7.4 and test it.

ad 2): adding the join-type mapping ang implementing the corresponding inserts etc. is currently worked on and will hopefully be available in version 4.1.